# Opening .tif drone photo in QGIS problem

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I need to open a .tif file in QGIS. The file is a large orto-photo taken by a drone. My colleague says opening it in ArcGIS works fine but I don't have access to it and I can't cant seem to open it in QGIS.

Here is what it looks like to me.

[image]

Does anyone know where I should start looking to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SE GIS!  It appears that your .tif is a *multiband* image (confirm by reviewing your .tif's **Layer Properties**).

I can recreate your problem with a sample multiband image, as follows. Using QGIS, open up the **Layer Styling** window (F7 from the layers pane) and select *Paletted/Unique values* from the drop-down.  Then click the *Classify* button.  Sure enough, the resulting .tif is displayed with a random, speckled coloring, similar to your image.

[image]

The solution is to select the *Multiband Color* drop-down, as shown below.  Voila!  Natural color is displayed (although in my example, a dry, drab area).

[image]